# Фотография стоит по левому краю. Как сделать, чтобы была в середине?

Tags: html, css

Есть такие теги

```
<div class="card">
 <div class="card-content">
 <img class="responsive-img" style="max-height: 64px;" src="http://idsoft.com.ar/javax.faces.resource/div.png.xhtml?ln=img"/>
                                        <div class="left-align">
    ....
    ...
    ...
```

Здесь фотография начинается с левого края. Как сделать, чтоб она стояла не слева а с середины??? Благодарю

Comment: Необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый лёгкий способ , поместить в тег `p` и в блоке `text-align:center;`

```css
div {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Стили для картинки. 
Margin:auto;
line-height: размер полный картинки